# Using OpenCV along with Pyttsx3 using multithreading but the screen in freezing continuously

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, text-to-speech, python-multithreading

I am trying to make an application that will use OpenCV to read the live stream from the webcam along with Python Text to speech (Pyttsx3) library which will simultaneously read out the text and give a live video from the webcam but the stream is freezed when it is speaking out text.
So I created separate threads to get the stream, show it, and also a separate thread for pyttsx3 but again the video gets freeze when it says out the text.

I have tried this code

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import pyttsx3

class VideoGet:
    """
    Class that continuously gets frames from a VideoCapture object
    with a dedicated thread.
    """

    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()
        self.stopped = False
        
    def start(self):    
        Thread(target=self.get, args=()).start()
        return self

    def get(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            if not self.grabbed:
                self.stop()
            else:
                (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True
        
        
        
class VideoShow:
    """
    Class that continuously shows a frame using a dedicated thread.
    """

    def __init__(self, frame=None):
        self.frame = frame
        self.stopped = False
        
    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.show, args=()).start()
        return self

    def show(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            cv2.imshow("Video", self.frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
                self.stopped = True

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True 



class CountsPerSec:
    """
    Class that tracks the number of occurrences ("counts") of an
    arbitrary event and returns the frequency in occurrences
    (counts) per second. The caller must increment the count.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._start_time = None
        self._num_occurrences = 0

    def start(self):
        self._start_time = datetime.now()
        return self

    def increment(self):
        self._num_occurrences += 1

    def countsPerSec(self):
        elapsed_time = (datetime.now() - self._start_time).total_seconds()
        #elapsed_time!=0
        return self._num_occurrences/elapsed_time 
    
    
def putIterationsPerSec(frame, iterations_per_sec):
    """
    Add iterations per second text to lower-left corner of a frame.
    """

    cv2.putText(frame, "{:.0f} iterations/sec".format(iterations_per_sec),
        (10, 450), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (255, 255, 255))
    return frame    


class TextToSpeech:
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine=pyttsx3.init(debug=True)
        #self.engine.startLoop(True)
    
    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.speech("i am "),args=()).start()
        return self
    
    def speech(self,saytext):
        self.engine.say(saytext)
        self.engine.runAndWait()
    
        
    def stop(self):
        self.stopped=True     
        
def threadBoth(source=0):
    """
    Dedicated thread for grabbing video frames with VideoGet object.
    Dedicated thread for showing video frames with VideoShow object.
     Dedicated thread for text to speech object.
    Main thread serves only to pass frames between VideoGet and
    VideoShow objects/threads.
    """
    #tts=TextToSpeech()
    tts1=TextToSpeech().start()
    video_getter = VideoGet(source).start()
    video_shower = VideoShow(video_getter.frame).start()
    
   
    cps = CountsPerSec().start()

    while True:
        if video_getter.stopped or video_shower.stopped:
            video_shower.stop()
            video_getter.stop()
            break
        tts1.speech("hey anmol")
        frame = video_getter.frame
        frame = putIterationsPerSec(frame, cps.countsPerSec())
        video_shower.frame = frame

threadBoth(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was looking for a way to implement this too. I found this to be working for me:

```
import pyttsx3
import threading
import queue

# To play audio text-to-speech during execution
  class TTSThread(threading.Thread):
 def __init__(self, queue):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.queue = queue
    self.daemon = True
    self.start()

def run(self):
    tts_engine = pyttsx3.init()
    tts_engine.startLoop(False)
    t_running = True
    while t_running:
        if self.queue.empty():
            tts_engine.iterate()
        else:
            data = self.queue.get()
            if data == "exit":
                t_running = False
            else:
                tts_engine.say(data)
    tts_engine.endLoop()

q = queue.Queue()
tts_thread = TTSThread(q)
```

and then you can change the text to use in your while loop by using:

```
q.put(text)
```